# can't see analytics for my action on Google Assistant.

Tags: actions-on-google

My action just got deployed on Google Assistant. Many users have used it, but still, I can't see analytics for it on my actions console. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your question is obscure and not descriptive. Please provide more details and clarification for our better understanding. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like some metrics are only available after few days like data in "Discovery" tab. For other tabs normally there are directly available even during developing phase.

Some analytics data are also available in the Dialoglow console if you use it.

Comment: yes, Thanks. I could see my analytics after a few days.